# What is 'command' on bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

If I type `command` on my terminal, I don't get "command not found", and the exit code is 0. I assume that this means `command` actually does something on bash.

Also, `command -h` returns:

```
bash: command: -h: invalid option
command: usage: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
```

What is it used for?

Comment: Have a look at the man page for command. It describes exactly what it does.

Comment: @n8te:  You should instead give a quick summary of what it does as an answer, also refering to the man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help command`:

```
$ help command
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
    Execute a simple command or display information about commands.

    Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing  shell function lookup, or display
    information about the specified COMMANDs.  Can be used to invoke commands
    on disk when a function with the same name exists.

    Options:
      -p    use a default value for PATH that is guaranteed to find all of
      the standard utilities
      -v    print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin
      -V    print a more verbose description of each COMMAND

    Exit Status:
    Returns exit status of COMMAND, or failure if COMMAND is not found.
```

As a more general note, rather than just using `-h` when you don't know what a command does, you should try:

```
type -a command
```

Which would in this case have told you it is a shell builtin.

```
help command
```

is good for shell builtins.  For other commands (and *also* for shell builtins, actually), try

```
man somecommand
```

Also, `-h` is not *necessarily* the "help" option.  If you don't know what a command does, that may not be a safe assumption to make.  Safer is `--help`.

```
somecommand --help
```

(Common commands where `-h` is a valid option but does *not* mean "help" are `ls`, `free`, `df`, `du`.  All of these are informational only, but the assumption that `-h` will only ever mean "help" is a dangerous assumption.)

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice on  -h. I have been using bash for a while, but I still make these kinds of mistakes often.

Comment: Although the help doesn't say so, `command xyz` also implicitly suppresses an alias `xyz` because `xyz` is no longer the first token.

Comment: @Wildcard could you explain what is the "shell function lookup" mentioned in the  manual?

Answer (score 0):

`command` like almost everything else Unix/Linux is documented in man pages.  Typing `man command` provides the manual for `bash` which has a subsection devoted to the built-in command `command`:

> command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
>
> Run  command  with  args  suppressing  the normal shell function lookup. Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH  are executed.   If the -p option is given, the search for command is performed using a default value for PATH that is  guaranteed  to find  all  of  the  standard  utilities.  If either the -V or -v option is supplied, a description of command is printed.  The -v  option  causes  a single word indicating the command or filename   used to invoke command to be displayed; the -V option produces a   more  verbose  description.  If the -V or -v option is supplied,   the exit status is 0 if command was found, and  1  if  not.   If  neither option is supplied and an error occurred or command cannot be found, the exit status is 127.  Otherwise, the exit  status of the command builtin is the exit status of command.