# What does "set -- command doas $@" do in my Bash function?

Tags: command, set

I use this Bash oneliner, `set -o errexit;set -o pipefail;set -o nounset;doas() { [[ "${EUID}" == '0' ]]||set -- command doas "${@}";"${@}";}` in the head of my scripts in order to prevent me from being asked for a password when I'm root. [From what I gathered](https://ss64.com/bash/set.html), if any arguments follow `--`, then the the positional parameters are set to the arguments. What does `command`do in my oneliner? Is it a Bash bult-in (`which command` returns nothing)? Would someone decode it and give another example of using `command`. Where can I read more about `command`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 'command' on bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319667/what-is-command-on-bash) - You define a function named `doas`, but you also need to execute the actual `doas` command, which is what `command doas` does.

Comment: See also: [Difference between command `command` vs command `builtin` in Shell Scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/651980/70524)